# Required Future[Either[Object1, Object2]] found Unit

Tags: scala

I have a method in `Scala` which will return `Future[Either[SecurityScanResponse, ScanResult]]` However after writing my logic, I am getting required `Future[Either[SecurityScanResponse, ScanResult]]` found `Unit` error.
Below is my implementation.

```
def calculateScore(penalties: Int): Future[Either[FootballScore, CricketScore]] = 
calculatePenalties(penalties).onComplete {
 case Success(penalResponse) => 
    if(penalResponse.valid) {
       findNumberOfMatches().onComplete {
            Future.successful(
                  Left(FootballScore(0, "Valid")))
 }
 case Failure(ex) => 
    log.error("Invalid penalties")
    Future.successful(
                  Left(FootballScore(0, "Invalid")))
  }
 }
}
```

This is just hypothetical code but I am focused upon solution of found `Unit` required `Future[Either[FootballScore, CricketScore]]`.

Comment: `flatMap` / `transformWith` rather than `onComplete`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the definition of [Future.onComplete](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.11/scala/concurrent/Future.html#onComplete%5BU%5D(f:scala.util.Try%5BT%5D=%3EU)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):Unit) you would see the following

> ```scala
> abstract def onComplete[U](f: (Try[T]) => U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit
> ```
>
> When this future is completed, either through an exception, or a value, apply the provided function.
>
> If the future has already been completed, this will either be applied immediately or be scheduled asynchronously.
>
> Note that the returned value of f will be discarded.

The method `onComplete` returns a `Unit`. That's why you are getting that error message.

You have a `Transformation` section in the docs that shows different method to apply some operation over a `Future`. Based on what you showed, I think `transform`, `transformWith`, `map` and `flatMap` will be the right ones for this case. Not sure how to rewrite your code because it has many functions that are not defined there and also the logic is hard to understand.